# Format date in Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, format

I have a function which accepts a UTC date. I want to return back the local date.
I have the following code so far:

```
    var dateFormat = function (date) {
        var dt = new Date(date + " UTC");
        return dt.toString(); 
       }
```

For the return date, I like it formatted as such:

```
     October 9th, 2013, 7:34:00 PM
```

Is there a formatting that will handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually use moment.js for this kind of tasks. It's pretty powerful and still small sized library. Give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. In my above example, how do I pass a date with moment.js Do not see how this is done.

Comment: @NatePet Take a look at http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/date/

Answer (score 0):

You have a lot of ways to format the `Date` object in JavaScript. I suggest you to check out *[10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/tips/html/10_ways_to_format_time_and_date_using_javascript.php3)* and *[Working with Dates](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/)*. These are the main functions you need to use for formatting JavaScript Dates:

```
getDate(): Returns the date
getMonth(): Returns the month (Starting from 0)
getFullYear(): Returns the year
```

A simple script would be:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var d = new Date();
    var curDate = d.getDate();
    var curMonth = d.getMonth() + 1; // Months are zero based
    var curYear = d.getFullYear();
    document.write(curDate + "-" + curMonth + "-" + curYear);
</script>
```

In your case, you can have an array of months:

```
var months = ["January", "February", ... "December"];
```

The next part would be associating the correct variables with the place they need to be present.

#### Plugins

But instead of doing all these, you can also consider using a fancy date formatter plugin, that uses jQuery or some library. A few ones would be:

1. [**Moment.js**](http://momentjs.com/) is a javascript date library for parsing, validating, manipulating, and formatting dates.
2. [**XDate**](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) is a thin wrapper around JavaScript's native Date object that provides enhanced functionality for parsing, formatting, and manipulating dates. It implements the same methods as the native Date, so it should seem very familiar.
3. [**DateJS**](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/) is an open source JavaScript Date library for parsing, formatting and processing.

Comment: getMonth() + 1: Returns the month